# combine two columns in 1 column mysql

Tags: mysql

i have tablea and table b

tablea :

```
Nama    Jumlah
A       66
B       95
C       47
E       57
F       52
```

tableb:

```
Nama    Jumlah  Gaji
A       35      47
B       28      51
C       18      24
D       27      30
E       30      29
G       31      16
```

how to make query that can combine two tables in one table an to be like this

result :

```
Nama    Jumlah  Gaji
A       101     47
B       123     51
C       65      24
D       27      30
E       87      29
F       52      0
G       31      16
```

it's my query. but i can't get the the result like that.

```
SELECT a.nama, (a.jumlahtotala+b.jumlahtotalb) AS Jumlah FROM (SELECT nama, SUM(jumlah) AS jumlahtotala FROM tablea GROUP BY nama) a JOIN (SELECT nama, SUM(jumlah) AS jumlahtotalb, SUM(gaji) AS gaji FROM tableb GROUP BY nama) b GROUP BY a.name
```

thanks for your help

**EDITED**
Sorry for another question in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Nama` is not unique in `tablea` or `tableb`, or if rows exist in `tablea` that don't have a matching row in `tableb`, for example:

tablea:

```
Nama    Jumlah
A       66
B       95
C       47
C       18
```

tableb:

```
Nama    Jumlah  Gaji
A       35      47
C       0       24   
D       27      30
Z       NULL    99
```

If an acceptable result is to return a single occurrence of each value of `Nama` along with the totals of `Jumlah` and `Gaji`, then one approach (assuming the datatypes of the `Nama` and `Jumlah` columns is compatible), and assuming that there isn't a requirement to return the rows in a particular sequence, one option is to combine the two sets with a `UNION ALL` operator into a derived table, and then use `SUM()` aggregate.

For example:

```
SELECT t.Nama
     , SUM(t.Jumlah) AS Jumlah
     , SUM(t.Gaji)   AS Gaji
  FROM ( SELECT b.Nama
              , b.Jumlah
              , b.Gaji
           FROM tableb b
          UNION ALL
         SELECT a.Nama
              , a.Jumlah
              , NULL
           FROM tablea a
       ) t
 GROUP BY t.Nama
```

Because of the derived table (i.e. the way that MySQL processes derived tables), this will likely *not* be the most efficient approach for large sets.

Answer (score 2):

Try joining the two tables like:

```
SELECT b.Nama, IFNULL(a.Jumlah, 0) + b.Jumlah, b.Gaji
FROM tablea a RIGHT JOIN tableb b
ON a.Nama = b.Nama
```

Comment: A bit wrong field name at `Jumlah`, must be `ISNULL(a.Jumlah, 0) + b.Jumlah`

Comment: woops typo! Thanks @ColourDalnet

Comment: i got an error `#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL' `

Comment: thanks @almas shaikh. but i have another question. if tablea has E row, but tableb has no E row.
see my new comment below
thanks

Comment: This query depends on the assumption that `Nama` column is unique in each of the two tables. (It is unique in the example data, the assumption may turn out to be true, but assumptions based on the extrapolation of limited sample data is dangerous.) This query also assumes that the result should exclude rows that exist in `tablea` that don't have a matching row in `tableb`. That may also be a valid assumption. But again, that assumption may be based on extrapolating limited sample data.